# Highcharts sort series data and redraw

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, highcharts, series

I have a problem with Highcharts. I need to sort series by button and then redraw chart with new data array. New series have right sorting

`const sortedSeries = [...series].sort(function (a, b)...`

but when I try to update chart:

`chart.update({ series: sortedSeries }`

they redraw with correct sorting but incorrect data inside series. Could you help?
Thanks a lot.

my code is in [here](https://jsfiddle.net/maxmsmax/rmx5okn2/11/) please check it.

Answer (score 0):

The data is incorrect because Highcharts for performance reasons mutates the original data. You can update the chart with completely new series array: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2rvctqpz/

or change only series index: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f94gocds/

```
    $('#button').click(function() {
      const sortedSeries = series.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (a.generic < b.generic)
          return -1;
        if (a.generic > b.generic)
          return 1;
        return 0;
      });

      chart.series.forEach(function(s) {
        const seriesRef = sortedSeries.find(function(sortedS) {
          return sortedS.generic === s.options.generic;
        });

        s.update({
          index: sortedSeries.indexOf(seriesRef)
        }, false);
      });

      chart.redraw();
    });
```

---

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter.index

Comment: Oh awesome, thanks a lot ppotaczek! One question why the data not updating in the graph? https://www.screencast.com/t/hwD2n0tPcfYX Legend order changed correctly according to sort conditions but X,Y point position not changed and remain the same as when init loading was. I expect the result after pressing the button 'Update' to change position from 'ABB', 'ABC', 'A' to 'A', 'ABB', 'ABC'

Comment: hm looks like it's because dataSorting, do you know how I can sort by generic type series?

Comment: Hi @Maksym, I am not sure how your case looks now. The examples that I have provided seem to work fine.

Comment: Yes, it's works great, but data coordinates not change. I need to change data coordinates for each item according to `series.sort` and if I try to do like: `$.each(sortedSeries, function(key, val) {
  val.data[0].x = key;
  val.data[1].x = key;
  chart.series[key].update(val);
});`

This works correctly but takes a very long time :( Could you help me to optimize or suggest something?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you present the problem in jsfiddle?

Comment: Sure https://jsfiddle.net/maxmsmax/sj1t3kpy/7/
Line: 55 overwrites x:0, x:1, x:2 ... and then the sorting is correct. But if I have more then 50 series data it takes a long time

Comment: The process is slow because you update the chart in every iteration. Something like this should be enough: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v0Lru6d3/

Comment: Yeeeeaaaah! Thanks